# Area under the histogram is not 1 when using density in plt.hist

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, distribution, probability-density

Consider the following dataset with random data:

```
test_dataset = np.array([ -2.09601881,  -4.26602684,   1.09105452,  -4.59559669,
         1.05865251,  -0.93076762, -14.70398945, -18.01937129,
         4.64126152, -10.34178822,  -9.46058493,  -5.66864965,
        -3.17562022,  15.7030379 ,  10.59675205,  -5.80882413,
       -24.00604149,  -4.81518663,  -1.94333927,   1.18142171,
        12.72030312,   3.84917581,  -0.4468796 ,  11.91828567,
       -17.99171774,   9.35108712,  -5.57233376,   5.77547128,
         5.49296099, -10.96132844, -18.75174336,   5.27843303,
        25.73548956, -21.58043021, -14.24734733,  12.57886018,
       -22.10002076,   1.72207555,  -6.0411867 ,  -3.63568527,
         7.26542117,  -0.21449529,  -6.64974714,  -0.94574606,
        -4.23339431,  16.76199734, -12.42195793,  18.965854  ,
       -23.85336123, -15.55104466,   6.17215868,   7.34993316,
         8.62461351, -16.30482638, -16.35601099,   1.96857833,
        18.74440399, -22.48374434, -10.895831  , -10.14393648,
       -17.62768751,   4.83388855,  20.1578181 ,   6.04299626,
         0.97198296,  -3.40889754, -10.62734293,   1.70240472,
        20.4203839 ,  10.26751364,  15.47859675, -10.97940064,
         1.82728251,   4.22894717,   8.31502887,  -5.48502811,
        -1.09244874, -11.32072796, -24.88520436,  -7.42108403,
        19.4200716 ,   4.82704045, -12.46290135, -15.18466755,
         6.37714692, -11.06825059,   5.10898588,  -9.07485484,
         1.63946084, -12.2270078 ,  12.63776832, -25.03916909,
         2.42972082, -14.22890171,  18.2199446 ,   6.9819771 ,
       -12.07795089,   2.59948596, -16.90206575,   6.35192719,
         7.33823106, -23.69653447, -11.66091871, -19.40251179,
       -12.64863792,  11.04004231,  13.7247356 , -16.36107329,
        20.43227515,  17.97334692,  16.92675175,  -5.62051239,
        -8.66304184,  -8.40848514, -23.20919855,   0.96808137,
        -5.03287253,  -3.13212582,  18.81155666,  -8.27988284,
         3.85708447,  12.43039322,  17.98003878,  18.11009997,
        -3.74294421, -16.62276121,   9.4446743 ,   2.2060981 ,
         8.34853736,  14.79144713,  -1.91113975,  -5.17061419,
         4.53451746,   8.19090358,   7.98343201,  11.44592322,
       -16.9132677 , -25.92554857,  10.10638432,  -8.09236786,
        20.8878207 ,  19.52368296,   0.85858125,   2.61760415,
         9.21360649,  -8.1192651 ,  -6.94829273,   2.73562447,
        13.40981323,  -9.05018331, -17.77563166, -21.03927199,
         4.10415845,  -1.31550732,   5.68284828,  15.08670773,
       -19.78675315,  12.94697869, -11.51797637,   1.91485992,
        16.69417993, -16.04271622,  -1.14028558,   9.79830109,
       -18.58386093,  -7.52963269, -10.10059878, -25.2194216 ,
        -0.10598426, -15.77641532, -14.15999125,  14.35011271,
        11.15178588, -14.43856266,  15.84015226,  -3.41221883,
        11.90724469,   0.57782081,  18.82127466,  -6.01068727,
       -19.83684476,   2.20091942,  -1.38707755,  -8.62821053,
       -11.89000913, -11.69539815,   5.70242019,  -3.83781841,
         5.35894135,  -0.30995954,  21.76661212,   8.52974329,
        -9.13065082, -11.06209   , -12.00654618,   2.769838  ,
       -12.21579496, -27.2686534 ,  -4.58538197,  -6.94388425])
```

I'd like to plot normalized histogram of it, so in the `plt.hist` options I choose `density=True`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1, bins, _ = plt.hist(test_dataset, density=True);
print(np.trapz(data1))
print(sum(data1))
```

which outputs the following histogram:

[image]

`0.18206124014272715`

`0.18866449755723017`

From [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/histogram_features.html):

> The density parameter, which normalizes bin heights so that the integral of the histogram is 1. The resulting histogram is an approximation of the probability density function.

But from my example it is clearly seen that the integral of the histogram is NOT 1 and strongly depends on the number of bins: if I specify it for example to be 40 the sum will increase:

```
data1, bins, _ = plt.hist(test_dataset, density=True);
print(np.trapz(data1))
print(sum(data1))
```

`0.7508847002777762`

`0.7546579902289207`

Is it incorrect description in documentation or I misunderstand some issues here?

Comment: documentation is correct, when you want to calculate the area under you should as well consider the width: sum(data1 * np.diff(bins)) == 1, in your examples bins are the same width. you can just all multiply on the width which are unique.

Comment: you are just summing the data, but not taking in account the width of the bins. Just adding data1 will give the area assuming the bins have width=1, which is not your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not calculate the area, area you should calculate as follow (in your example):

```
sum(data1 * np.diff(bins)) == 1
```

Comment: thanl you, it helped!)

Comment: Note that due to floating point approximation, often the sum will be slightly different from 1.